# Wrong order of input messages

Tags: graylog2

Is there any known problem regarding input message receive order in graylog? I have problems on graylog (using both gelf udp and syslog udp), messages are displayed in wrong order. Several messages are displayed with the same timestamp which is not possible, so we have lot of problems reading logs in messages section because messsages are received in same milisecond and not ordered as sent from client. I suppose there is a problem with input message buffering on graylog server side. Receive buffer is set to 262144.

Comment: Why do you say that it's not possible to have several messages with the same timestamp?

Comment: Whenever I was using file appender in log4net messages were ordered normally, now I realized I have a problem with this mixing on graylog. Maybe it is using some sequnce id in background which is used to know how to order messages proper way in file appender, but this mechanism is not user in graylog